# iOS modify the layer of a UIElements that are created with IB

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield, uitextview, uielement

In my app, I would like to create a custom `UIElement`, in my case a `UITextView` with rounded corners and border color and everything. however I can only do it if I create the `UITextView` from code and add it to a view with the `addSubView` method.

That's not too elegant, plus it fails during the unit tests as well.

Is there a way how I can create my `UITextView` with using Interface Bulder and still being able to modify its layer property?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an `IBOutlet` by ctrl-dragging from the nib or storyboard to your .h file, you can access your graphical element as usual with something like `myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;`.

Comment: what asked for was not an issue in the first place :) 
Thank you very much for your answer!